# How to manually add Gradle module to Android project?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm working on a project that was created before Gradle became the build system for Android development (LibreOffice Viewer for Android). When the project was migrated to Gradle, it didn't reorganize the folder structure to the new one Android is using, and so the Gradle config has things like:

```
        main.manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        main.assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        main.res.srcDirs = ['res']
        main.java.srcDirs = ['../Bootstrap/src', 'src/java']
        main.jniLibs.srcDirs = ['jniLibs']
```

in the `build.gradle` file in the root of the project, while "usual" Gradle projects have one file in the root of the project, and one in each of the modules.

My question is, is it enough to create a new folder for the module, and create a new `build.gradle` file within it (and then move the appropriate files etc.)? Is that the "correct" way of adding a new module manually, or do I have to "declare" that module somewhere else, for it to work correctly, and be recognized by Android Studio?

Comment: you need to also add it in `settings.gradle` assuming you're using A.S.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is definitely possible to do this manually, as I did it for literally [hundreds of book sample apps](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus).

You listed these steps:

- Create a new folder for the module (here, I'll call it `app`)
- Create a new `build.gradle` file within it
- Move the appropriate files

You also need to:

- Add your module to `settings.gradle`, creating that file if needed (or copying it from an existing Android Studio project)
- Have your `app/build.gradle` correctly reflect the locations of the moved files, which could include removing stuff like `main.assets.srcDirs`, if your files are now all in standard locations (the way that you would find in a newly-created Android Studio project)
- Add a new project-level `build.gradle` file, probably just copied from some standard Android Studio project

In terms of Android Studio itself, I strongly recommend doing this project reorganization *outside* of Studio. Then, delete generated Studio items (all `.iml` files, `.idea/` subdirectory, `build/` directories), and finally import the project back into Studio.

Comment: could you elaborate in the "appropriate files" please? For someone doing this the first time, it would be very helpful if you give more details on that if you don't mind.

Comment: @The_Martian: Basically, whatever you would be putting into version control. Obvious candidates are your Java code, your resources, your manifest, and your assets. If you're using the NDK, your JNI code would need to move, and you probably need to replace the classic makefiles with CMake ones. But the answer can be quite a bit different if you are using some major framework (Unity3D, PhoneGap, etc.), and you would need to seek out instructions more suitable to such projects.

Comment: I appreciate your prompt response. I don't have native code as of right now. I added all the java files in a app/src/main/java and referenced them in build.gradle. But all the Java files have red circle on them and I cannot run the project on my device. There are no exceptions thrown, neither can I see any errors from AS. Do you have any clue?

Comment: @The_Martian: I do not know what you mean by "cannot run the project on my device". You may want to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve], showing your Gradle scripts, project structure, and more detailed symptoms.

Comment: I just asked a new question, here is a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688113/imported-project-unable-to-run-in-android-studio