# Imported project unable to run in Android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I imported `Google's` HelloAr project after downloading and decompiling the code. I followed the [accepted answer in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041105/how-to-manually-add-gradle-module-to-android-project/42041173?noredirect=1#comment82332732_42041173) to create all necessary folders. Then I imported it into android studio. But now I am unable to run the project.

**build.gradle:**

[image]

**Modules :**

[image]

**UnityPlayerActivity:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Android SDK is not specified` is a problem with your project setup

Comment: exit the project and delete .idea folder and again open in android studio.

Comment: @cricket_007: I think that error is a false flag, because I have set my sdk just like the image I just added indicates.

Comment: Your project SDK should probably be an Android one

Comment: Other than that, what exactly is the problem? Can you run Gradle tasks outside of Android Studio for your project?

Comment: When I try to add module manually in the edit run configurations, I don't have "app", but "unnamed" in the drop down list to choose from. What causes that? What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was missing

> settings.gradle

file at the root of the project. Android studio will not automatically add it for you. You have to manually add it to your root before you import the project into AS.